# Using US foreign tax policy to offset a raise in interest rates

Tags: monetary-policy, money-supply, taxation

I am an amateur economist at best, more a person with an economic BS looking to explore data science (I will be using python). I have a theory that I want opinion on that will allow the Fed to raise the interest rate while offsetting the lose in domestic investment by lowering or eliminating the [repatriate tax laws](http://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21642196-presidents-plan-makes-no-sense-offer-they-could-refuse).

My assumptions are that raising the interest rates will lower investment overall, lower the money supply, and decrease demand.  That lowering the repatriate tax laws will have American firms import a higher level of liquid capital, spur domestic investment, and create jobs.

Ultimately I want to make a formula with as little dependencies as possible where $f(x)+g(y)=0$. $f(x)$ will be the effect on the economy due to the interest rate and $g(y)$ will be the effect of the tax. So if you raise the interest rate $f(x)$ then you must lower the repatriate tax rate $g(y)$.

My questions are:

**1)** Are you aware of a study like this?

**2)** Are my assumptions correct?

**3)** Any advice would be greatly appreciated such as data sources, economic papers on parts of what I am trying to do, possible factors to include.

**4)** Just looking at it, does it seem logical?